# Am I banned from entering the USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals

Am a Nigerian.  I applied for a visiting visa in October 2014 but was denied visa because I had a fake stamp of another country on my passport (not USA). I did it because I was having a problem at my place of work but it the fact that it was fake was detected at the US embassy. The passport will expire Jan 2016.

How likely is it that I'll be banned from entering the USA?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it can not be answered. You need to ask the embassy.

Comment: @NeanDerThal I also thought so, but a bit of research indicates it is answerable, so I've done so below.

Comment: What was the actual reason given for the visa refusal?  It will likely be a series of numbers and letters.

Answer (score 6):

At least [one US Immigration law firm](http://www.murthy.com/2013/03/12/impact-on-visa-from-misrepresentation-and-fraud/) cites the Immigration and Nationality Act (INA) section 212(a)(6)(C)(i):

> "The result of fraud findings is that such individuals are
>   inadmissible to the United States. These applicants are not allowed to
>   enter the U.S. or adjust status to permanent residence. "

It's worth reading their whole page on the subject.

Many people claim that they were misguided by lawyers, consultants or immigration agencies, however, ultimate the onus is on the individual.

Does this mean you have no hope? There is a slim chance:

> In limited circumstances, waivers are available as a way to obtain
>   forgiveness for the fraud or misrepresentation, and to allow entry to
>   the U.S. These waivers are available in both the nonimmigrant
>   (temporary) and immigrant (permanent) context. However, such waivers
>   are highly discretionary and can be difficult to obtain.

Comment: 212(a)(6)(C)(i) may or may not be relevant.  Presuming that the fabricated stamp wasn't relevant to the US visa application, then this entire section most likely does not apply.

Comment: Well it does say a 'finding of fraud or misrepresentation' without specifying the US, but perhaps what you describe is then under the waiver option :/  I guess this is why there are lawyers for this sort of thing.

Comment: Am So grateful for the response So far. 
please what can be done to rectify the error because my office will be sending me for a training in USA next year April and they are not informed about my case with the embassy

Comment: I think it should actually be an edit to this question.  It's too similar to be asked as a new question (and when it was, it was closed: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55948/how-can-i-rectify-my-passport-error-with-the-usa-embassy).  But you're right, not a comment.